# How to call generic method of wildcard type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I found I can't call generic methods of wildcard types and don't understand why?

```
public class GenericsTry2 {

    public static class Element {

        private Container<? extends Element> container;

        public Container<? extends Element> getContainer() {
            return container;
        }

        public void setContainer(Container<? extends Element> container) {
            this.container = container;
        }

        public  void doStuff() {
            getContainer().doStuff(this); // how to call this?
        }
    }

    public static class SomeSubElement extends Element {
    }

    public static class SomeSubElement2 extends Element {
    }

    public static class Container<E extends Element> {

        public void doStuff(E element) {
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Container<SomeSubElement2> c = new Container<SomeSubElement2>();

        Element e = new SomeSubElement();

        c.doStuff((SomeSubElement2) e); // still can do this at compile time this way

    }


}
```

Answer (score 9):

Having `Container<? extends Element>` means that [the `Container` can only **produce** `Element`(s), but cannot **consume** `Element`(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs).

The reason for this is that `? extends Element` denotes a whole family of *unknown* sub-types of `Element`. Let's assume you set your container to `Container<SomeSubElement>`. Then, passing `this` to the container (even you know it's an `Element`, or a sub-type of `Element`) won't be correct, because `this` may be or may not be `SomeSubElement` (depends on the Runtime type).

In the world of Generics, this is called co-variance.

In order to have the code compiling (I don't guarantee that you need exactly this), you can do (note that I've changed the container to be consumer of `Element`(s), instead of producer):

```
public class Element {

    private Container<? super Element> container;

    public Container<? super Element> getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

    public void setContainer(Container<? super Element> container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public  void doStuff() {
        getContainer().doStuff(this);
    }
}
```

However, if you need your `Container` to be a producer and a consumer at the same time, just get rid of the wildcard and parameterize it with `<Element>` only.

Comment: I agree with you words about `SubSubElement`. By please see my updated code. I have created `SubSubElement` and it's sibling and I was able pass it wrongly in `main` method. It is causing runtime exception. So I don't understand, why should it cause compile time error at first case?

Comment: Well, it' natural. `SomeSubElement` cannot be `SomeSubElement2` and you get a Runtime Exception, because the cast happens at Runtime. With the explicit cast you tell the compiler *"I know that the type of `e` at Runtime will be compatible with `SomeSubtype2`, so please trust me and compile my code"*, however `SomeSubElement` is not compatible with `SomeSubElement2` and thus you get the exception..

Answer (score 1):

`Container<E extends Element>` means that it contains something `E` that extends from `Element`. Not necessarily the `Element` itself.

Imagine what would happen if you'll have:

```
Container<RedElement> redElements = new Container<RedElement>();
Container<E extends Element> container = redElements;

// According to your logic it will work
container.add(new Element());

// Problem here. You just put Element there which is not RedElement.
RedElement element = container.getFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getContainer()` Method guarantees to return some object of a class that extends Element. So the compiler does not know at this point that the returned value is actually of type `Container`. If you want to call the `doStuff()`-Method of the `Container` class, you have to cast the result of `getContainer()` to the type `Container` explicitly.

```
((Container) getContainer()).doStuff(this);
```